# TRIM en mysql solo funciona en inicio y final de la cadena

Tags: mysql

Tengo un campo que tiene el siguiente valor

> ```
>                                                    RISARALDA                  Estación Pereira amaneció inundada
> ```

Esta con muchos espacios innecesarios, cuando hago un select TRIM() no me quita todos los espacios del medio, solo los de  extremos.

Si pego el valor aqui en stack no me muestra los espacios pero seria algo asi:

```
Los espacios representados con los puntos
```

> RISARALDA    ................              Estación Pereira amaneció inundada

Query:

```
SELECT *,TRIM(titulo)  as trimtitulo  FROM noticias WHERE id=2797254;
```

SOLUCIONADO

creo entender que el trim no toma los "tabs" en los strings (creo no estoy seguro, pero esta funcion lo soluciona)

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION trimMejorado(str LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
BEGIN
    while instr(str, '  ') > 0 do
        set str = replace(str, '    ',' ');
    end while;
    while instr(str, '  ') > 0 do
        set str = replace(str, '  ',' ');
    end while;
    return trim(str);
end //
```

Comment: Eso es lo que hace la función TRIM(), extrae los espacios en blando de la cadena hacia su derecha e izquierda. Pero te pregunto, que es lo que necesitas? Ver únicamente la columna de esta forma: "RISARALDA Estación Pereira amaneció inundada" o quieres actualizarla permanentemente?!.

Comment: Pues en realidad necesito actualizarla, pero pues queria ver como van a quedar esos campos (que son muchos), ya mande un update y quedan igual como se ven con esos espacios intermedios  :/

Comment: lo más sencillo (pero no es una respuesta completa), sería hacer updates varias veces hasta que los registros actualizados sean cero: `UPDATE noticias  SET titulo = REPLACE(titulo,'  ',' ');`. Extrañamente el código no se ve bien en el comentario, pero el replace está reemplazando dos espacios continuos por un solo espacio

Comment: Esto puede ayudarte [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971705/5675636]

Comment: Wow Muchisimas gracias!; actualizo el post con la respuesta :) mil gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te funcione, personalmente no lo había probado.